# Why spring bootstrap properties change at different profiles?

Tags: java, spring

I've got spring bootstrap.yml file with the following properties

```
spring.cloud:
  config:
    uri: http://${SERVICE_HOST}/${PROJECT_KEY}-config-server
    enabled: true
    failFast: true
```

I try to make my config server client (configured by the props above) work with the **production** profile, but at runtime my config server client is disabled:

```
ConfigClientProperties properties = applicationContext.getBean(ConfigClientProperties.class);
log.info("Profile is " + properties.getProfile());
log.info("Enabled is " + properties.isEnabled());
```

prints

```
Profile is production

Enabled is false
```

At **test** profile everything is ok.

How can I enable my config server client at production environment?

Comment: Just to rule it out as a cause: what happens when you break the `spring.cloud` up into the proper yaml nested structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They were overrided by a marathon app we use to deploy applications. Spring doesn't override props

Answer (score 2):

Seems that your yml is not in the correct format (spring.cloud). From the  [official documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html) under the chapter 
 `The Bootstrap Application Context`

`spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: ${SPRING_CONFIG_URI:http://localhost:8888}`

Try changing `spring.cloud` to the above example and let me know if it helps.

Comment: Yeah good for you, have my upvote. I should have just posted an answer instead of waiting hours for the OP to respond :/

Answer (score -1):

In the default way the maven or gradle use default profile (in the normal situation default profile is dev).
to the spring boot that i want build with the different profile you can use:

for maven:

`mvnw -Pprod spring-boot:run
OR
./mvnw -Pprod spring-boot:run`

for gradle:

`gradlew -Pprod bootRun
OR
./gradlew -Pprod bootRun`

and a profile with the name of prod must declare in your project (ex. .yml files).